# rewrite function to not use echo php for use with short_code

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a bit of trouble getting my shortcode to place my html of a function in the correct place on wordpress. After some research I have found that when using shortcodes you cannot have `echo` used in the function. I have been doing my best to write the function without any `echo`'s but cant seem to get it to work. I have little actual experience with PHP as a language and am giving this my best shot.

The top code block is the functioning code with `echo` used throughout, and the second is the rewritten code without any `echo` but is not functioning. Anyone have an idea where my rewrite is going wrong? Or possibly have a better work around then rewriting the function?

First:

```
function na_get_gallery_image_urls( $post_id ) {

$post = get_post($post_id);

// Make sure the post has a gallery in it
if( ! has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) )
    return;

//initiate counter to be able to keep track of images
$count_img = 0;  

// Retrieve all galleries of this post
$gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post );


// Loop through each image in first gallery
foreach( $gallery as $image ) {

 // Below here are the main containers and first large image; stuff we will only want to output one time.
 if($count_img == 0) { ?>

   <!-- Whole Gallery container (inludes thumbnails) -->
   <div id="instant-gallery">

     <!-- Main Display Area -->
     <div id="ig-main">

         <!-- Set the parameters for the image we are about to display. -->
         <?php 
         $default_attr = "ig-hero";
         ?>

         <!-- Display the first image attachment as the large image in the main gallery area -->
         <img src="<?php print $image; ?>" id="<?php print $default_attr; ?>">

         <a href="<?php print $image; ?>" download>Download</a>

     <!-- Close the main display area -->
     </div>

     <!-- Open the Thumbnail navigation -->
     <ul id="ig-thumbs">

  <!-- End the block of stuff that we only do for the first image  --> 
  <?php } ?>

  <!-- Now, for each of the thumbnail images, label the LI with an ID of the        appropriate thumbnail number -->
  <li id="ig-thumb-<?php print $count_img+1; ?>">

  <?php if ($count_img==0) {

   // If this is the first thumbnail, add a class of 'selected' to it so it will be highlighted
   $thumb_attr = "thumb selected";

   } else {

   // For all other thumbnails, just add the basic class of 'thumb'
   $thumb_attr = "thumb";

   } ?>

  <!-- Output a thumbnail-sized version of the image that has the attributes defined above -->
 <img src="<?php print $image; ?>" class="<?php print $thumb_attr; ?>">

 </li>

 <!-- Increment the counter so we can keep track of which thumbnail we are on -->
 <?php $count_img = $count_img + 1; } ?>

 <!-- Close the thumbnail navigation list -->
 </ul>

 <!-- Close the entire Gallery -->
  </div>

  <?php 

  }



 function instant_gallery() {

  global $post;

  $args = array(
    'post_parent'    => '$post->ID',            // For the current post
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',       // Get all post attachments
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',            // Only grab images
    'order'          => 'ASC',              // List in ascending order
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',       // List them in their menu order
    'numberposts'    => -1,                 // Show all attachments
    'post_status'    => null,               // For any post status
  );

 // Retrieve the items that match our query; in this case, images attached to the current post.
na_get_gallery_image_urls($args[0]);

 }

  // Create the Shortcode
 add_shortcode('instant_gallery', 'instant_gallery');

  ?>
```

last:

```
  function na_get_gallery_image_urls( $post_id ) {

  $post = get_post($post_id);     

  // Make sure the post has a gallery in it
  if( ! has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) )
    return;

  // initiate counter to be able to keep track of images
  $count_img = 0;  

  // Retrieve all galleries of this post
  $gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post );  

  // Loop through each image in first gallery
  foreach( $gallery as $image ) {

   // Below here are the main containers and first large image; stuff we will only want to output one time.
  if($count_img == 0) { 

   //<!-- Whole Gallery container (inludes thumbnails) -->
   $hero_img = '<div id="instant-gallery">';

     //<!-- Main Display Area -->
     $hero_img .= '<div id="ig-main">';

         //<!-- Set the parameters for the image we are about to display. -->

         $default_attr = "ig-hero";

         //<!-- Display the first image attachment as the large image in the main gallery area -->
         $hero_img .= '<img src="' . $image . '" id="' . $default_attr . '">';

         $hero_img .= '<a href="' . $image . '" download>Download</a>';

         //close main display area 
         $hero_img .= '</div>';       

         //<!-- Open the Thumbnail navigation -->
        $hero_img .= '<ul id="ig-thumbs">';

        //<!-- End the block of stuff that we only do for the first image  --> 
      } 

      //<!-- Now, for each of the thumbnail images, label the LI with an ID of the appropriate thumbnail number -->
      $thumbs = '<li id="ig-thumb-' . ($count_img + 1) . '">';

  if ($count_img==0) {

    // If this is the first thumbnail, add a class of 'selected' to it so it will be highlighted
   $thumb_attr = "thumb selected";

  } else {

   // For all other thumbnails, just add the basic class of 'thumb'
   $thumb_attr = "thumb";

  } 

  //<!-- Output a thumbnail-sized version of the image that has the attributes defined above -->
  $thumbs .= '<img src="' . $image . '" class="' . $thumb_attr . '">' .  '</li>';



 //<!-- Increment the counter so we can keep track of which thumbnail we are on -->
  $count_img = $count_img + 1; 
 } 

 //<!-- Close the thumbnail navigation list -->
 $fin = '</ul>';

 // <!-- Close the entire Gallery -->
$fin .= '</div>';

$content = "$hero_img" . "$thumbs" . "$fin";

return $content;

}


 function instant_gallery() {

  global $post;

  $args = array(
    'post_parent'    => '$post->ID',            // For the current post
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',       // Get all post attachments
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',            // Only grab images
    'order'          => 'ASC',              // List in ascending order
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',       // List them in their menu order
    'numberposts'    => -1,                 // Show all attachments
    'post_status'    => null,               // For any post status
  );

    // Retrieve the items that match our query; in this case, images attached to         the current post.
na_get_gallery_image_urls($post->ID);

}

// Create the Shortcode
add_shortcode('instant_gallery', 'instant_gallery');

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Try below code with changing your parameters it will works.

```
function testgallery_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts(
    array(
    'title' =>'TEST GALLERY',
    'items' =>3,
    ), $atts )
    );

    $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'testgallery',
            'posts_per_page' => $items,
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
    );

    $test_gallery = new WP_Query( $args );

    $html = '';

        global $post;
        if ( $test_gallery->have_posts() ) :while ( $test_gallery->have_posts() ) : $test_gallery->the_post();
        $html.='<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">';
        $html.='<figure class="post">';
        $html.='<div class="image-wrap">';
        $html.='<a class="zoomtoplay" alt="gallery_image" href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ).'"></a>';
        if (has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $imgarray = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'full');
            $imgURL = $imgarray[0];
            $html.='<img src="'.$imgURL.'" class="img-responsive"/>';
        }
        $html.='<a href="'.esc_url( get_permalink() ).'"></div><h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3></a>';
        $html.='</figure>';
        $html.='</div>';

        endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_query();

    return $html;

}
add_shortcode( 'testgallery', 'testgallery_shortcode' );
```

-- Now you can use a [testgallery] shortcode in your post and page.

This is a standard way of creating shortcode.

Still if needed than For more details you can visit this link - https://www.sitepoint.com/custom-shortcodes-for-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks!! In my previous functions I was using `get_post_gallery_images();` do I still use that as well as incorporate this?

Comment: No you don't need to use that function now , you can directly pass your post structure from here which i have done in example

Comment: Thanks again @ManthanDave ! I will put in my parameters/structure and mark the question answered once I get it working

Comment: So I was not able to get this solution to work correctly. So I decided to stick to what I know best and change the page layout with CSS to make my gallery have a value `position: absolute` on the main container id and then messed around with the margins of the various elements until the page looked good. [You can checkout the page here.](http://nine10photo.com/gallerypage/) The top gallery is the one implemented. Thanks again @Manthan for helping me out.

Comment: @TimothyGriffith No worries Keep helping :)